# Add to dictionary specified item

Tags: python

I have to print some items and assign a number to them, so based on the number i have to add the item of corresponding number to a dictionary. For example I have an output like this :

1. blue
2. red
3. green
4. yellow

And if i choose 2 red should be added in my dictionary. How can I do this?

```
def colour():
pencil ={'blue':20, 'pink':12, 'red':18, 'green':10, 'black':15, 'yellow':6}
n = 0
find= raw_input('search for a colour: ')
choosen_item={}
for x in pencil :
    if find in x :
        n+=1
        print n,'.', x

colour()
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Show us your current work and we can offer suggestions.

Comment: It sounds like you already have a dictionary (The mapping of numbers to colors) and you want to use that to translate inputs.

Comment: It's unclear as to what you are asking. Can you please post what ever code you may have?

Comment: @JacobPersi i posted my code

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match your post, can you explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to keep track of the items the user enters so long as the item exists within the pencil dict?

Comment: @JacobPersi I will create a int(input) to ask the user for the colour, then the user has to enter a number and the colour which is that number has to be added in the empty list i have .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def process_user_input():
    valid_options = {'blue':20, 'pink':12, 'red':18, 'green':10, 'black':15, 'yellow':6};
    choosen_item  = {};

    user_input = raw_input('search for a colour: ');

    for key, value in valid_options.iteritems():
        if int(user_input) == value:
            choosen_item[key] = value;

    print(choosen_item);

process_user_input();

# search for a colour:  20
# {'blue': 20}
```